# layout_anchor and layout_anchorGravity do not work as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anyone know if this screenshot

[image]

reflects this layout correctly?

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF80"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
        android:text="@string/text_1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/text_view1"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        android:background="#FFFF8080"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
        android:text="@string/text_2"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/text_view2"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        android:background="#FF8080FF"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
        android:text="@string/text_3"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I was not expecting any overlap of text views, but may be my expectations are not correct?

Comment: Yes, the outcome is expected: the center of text_view3 is anchored to the right bottom corner of text_view2

Comment: So the question really is: How do I move a View to right of a view in a cordinatorLayout...? I'm wondering the same

Comment: @Wärting I ended up creating a custom behavior to lay child views out.  May be there are easier ways of doing that which I haven't found out yet.

Comment: @Wärting I think you only need to add `android:layout_gravity="right"` in addition to `app:layout_anchorGravity="right"`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As @ana 01 mention in comment, you should add `android:layout_gravity="right"` in addition to `app:layout_anchorGravity="right"`. By default `app:layout_anchorGravity`works like if a dependent view aligns to an anchor's view by the center of the anchor's view.

So if you would like to align one view relatively to other, you should set an edge or gravity of a dependent view which will be used for alignment through out `android:layout_gravity` attribute.